How to get access Token from Amadesu API on Python
I can't get access token from Amadeus Flight API authentication process using requests and oauth_lib.
https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/developer-guides/API-Keys/authorization/#requesting-an-access-token
Using Requests
import requests

API_KEY = "twAtndd5V..."
API_SECRET = "xtj..."
AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token/"
head = {"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
response = requests.post(
            url=AUTH_ENDPOINT,
            json={"grant_type" : "client_credentials",
                "client id" : API_KEY,
                "client_secret" : API_SECRET},
            headers=head
)
print(response.text)

        {
            "error":"invalid_request",      
            "error_description": "No access_token parameter needed for this method",    
            "code": 38187,
            "title": "Invalid parameters"   
        }

Try with oauth2 https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#backend-application-flow
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient

client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=API_KEY)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=AUTH_ENDPOINT, client_id=API_KEY, client_secret=API_SECRET)

    token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=AUTH_ENDPOINT, client_id=API_KEY, client_secret=API_SECRET)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 406, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
  File "C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\base.py", line 427, 
in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, 
scope=scope)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 441, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)       
  File "C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 448, in validate_token_parameters
    raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)
  File "C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\errors.py", line 399, in raise_from_error
    raise cls(**kwargs)
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientIdError: (invalid_request) No access_token parameter needed for this method


In your code, try the endpoint without the forward slash at the end:
AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token"

I had the same problem and this worked.

OMG! Thanks you. It works with oauth2 method.

Using the requests method we have to change:
json={"grant_type" : "client_credentials",
                     "client id" : API_KEY,
                     "client_secret" : API_SECRET

to:
data={"grant_type" : "client_credentials",
                     "client id" : API_KEY,

because we are sending the parameters as JSON, but the Amadeus API expects them to be sent as form-encoded data.

This answer makes no sense. The code examples and the text seem unrelated.
